# performance variation zend_pdf 2 vs tcpdf .

Tags: pdf, zend-framework2, tcpdf, zend-pdf

I have used zend framework and now want to use zf2. I used zend_pdf for zf1. I know some difference between tc_pdf and zend_pdf version 1 but no idea about zend_pdf verison 2. If anyone have idea about zend_pdf verion 2 then give me a brief about zf2 zend_pdf comparing to tc_pdf. Also if any pdf is better than tc_pdf and zend_pdf please give me some suggation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Zend_Pdf` from ZF2 is functionally the same as `Zend_Pdf` from ZF1. Also, `Zend_Pdf` isn't actually a part of ZF2 core any more.

`TCPDF` is a slightly higher level API so it is a bit easier to get started with. Plus, you don't have to worry about autoloading - just `require()` it in your source. `TCPDF` handles international characters well, including right-to-left rendering of text, which `Zend_Pdf` does not.

`Zend_Pdf` on the other hand, supports reading existing documents into memory and manipulating them (eg. adding pages to them, pulling pages out, manipulating existing pages, using fonts that are already embedded, etc), which `TCPDF` does not.

This is by no means a thorough comparison, but if any of the points mentioned above are critical requirements, then that will probably dictate which one you'll use. If none of the points above are critical requirements, then I would recommend you spend a bit more time looking at the API of each library and choosing the one that is the best fit for your requirements, coding style, etc. They are both great libraries.

[UPDATE - June 2013] I was just doing some work with transparent images and discovered that `TCPDF` is much more performant than `Zend_Pdf` in this area. I wrote a script that created a page, added an image and then added a second, transparent image on top of that image. I looped through to create 100 pages. `Zend_Pdf` from ZF1 took 14 seconds. `ZendPdf` from github (ie. the version that got split off from ZF2) took 13 seconds. TCPDF took 3 seconds. This may be significant for some people, hence I thought it worthwhile updating this answer. (By way of comparison, when I substituted a non-transparent image for the second image, both versions of `Zend_Pdf` completed the task in under a second, so the transparency was definitely the cause of the slow down).

Comment: Thanks for your nice comparison. I have got my answer between two. Please brother can you specify what is the better pdf library comparing all the pdf library.

Comment: I think a comprehensive article comparing all of the available PDF libraries would be beyond the scope of an SO answer. Also, picking a winner is impossible, because none of the libraries can do everything. If, on the other hand, you're just looking for an opinion from someone who has used a few different libraries, I will happily offer one. Assuming you don't need to read in existing documents and modify them, I would recommend TCPDF, as I think the API is easier to use. And I should point out that I have been using Zend products for three years, so its not like I'm anti-Zend or anything.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.